# Within the Chaplin js framework, what do the events prefixed with ! mean?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling, coffeescript, chaplinjs

I have seen these events sprinkled throughout chaplin example code, but there are no explanations within the documentation or the source. It seems that it means it is a global event, that triggers an action. Is that correct? Are they just a  convention, or are they enforced in some way?

```
# Handle login
@subscribeEvent 'logout', @logout
@subscribeEvent 'userData', @userData

# Handler events which trigger an action

# Show the login dialog
@subscribeEvent '!showLogin', @showLoginView
# Try to login with a service provider
@subscribeEvent '!login', @triggerLogin
# Initiate logout
@subscribeEvent '!logout', @triggerLogout
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from a [GitHub issue regarding the same question](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/issues/170):

> `!logout` is more a inter-module message or command. It allows one
>   module to trigger the logout (for example a view with a logout
>   button). The actual logout process is then handled by another module
>   (for example the session controller). This module invalidates the
>   session on the server, for example. When successful, it emits a `logout`
>   event which means the `logout` has happened. All modules which are
>   interested in login/logout should subscribe to `logout`.

I think that explains it pretty well. Basically the `!` event is triggered when the action is initiated, and the normal event is triggered when the action was successful.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks, I had a tough time searching for the !.